# Make background behind PNG logo transparent on hover (beginner)

Tags: css, mediawiki

I'm working on a website and am struggling with one thing.  Basically, when you hover over the main logo, the background of the logo goes white and it looks awful.  I've tried this in three different browsers.  Apart from the mouse pointer changing to a link indicator, I don't want any other visual changes on hover.  This is a bootstrap based mediawiki theme if that helps.

The site is: [www.nebdat.com](http://www.nebdat.com)

I've figured out that that section is called p-logo and have tried the following:

```
#p-logo:hover { background-color: transparent !important; }
```

It doesn't seem to do anything though.  However, when I try:

```
#p-logo:hover { opacity: 0; }
```

the logo and background all go transparent, so I know it's the right name of the object.  However, I want the logo name to remain.

I hope that makes sense.  I'm pretty new to this.

Hope you have some advice.

Thanks,

JT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#p-logo > a {
    background: transparent;
}
```

It's not the image that's got a background on hover, it's the anchor tag.

Comment: BTW, How did you figure that out?  I was using Firebug and it should the hover, not the "> a" unless I was just missing it.

Answer (score 3):

```
@media screen
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

That's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to override it, you can simply remove it. Find and remove this code from load.php:

```
img:hover{background:white url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAAAAAA6mKC9AAAAGElEQVQYV2N4DwX/oYBhgARgDJjEAAkAAEC99wFuu0VFAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;background:white url(http://www.nebdat.com/wiki/skins/common/images/Checker-16x16.png?2013-05-25T13:38:20Z) repeat!ie}
```